# Calculating sum of columns in uneven 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I've been teaching myself Java through some free online tutorials and have challenged myself to work through just about all of the practice exercises.  I've been stuck on this one for a week now and it's driving me crazy.  I feel I am fairly close, just tripped up by the varying array lengths that make up the uneven columns.

```
            public class Testing {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
                                     {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                                     {9, 1, 0, 2},
                                     {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };

                    int sum = 0;
                    int row = 0;
                    int col = 0;
                    int currentRow = 0;

                    while (currentRow < data.length) {
                        for (col = 0; col < data[currentRow].length; col++) {
                            sum = 0;
                            for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
                                System.out.println(data[row][col]);
                                sum += data[row][col];
                            }
                            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
                        } 
                        currentRow++;
                    }   
                }
            }
```

Comment: it seems as if there is one loop too much. Your `while` walks through the first dimension and `for(row...` the second dimension. So there is no need to walk through data again by `for(row...``

Comment: by sums of the columns do you mean the sum of element x in each array, so in your case, the sum of the first column would be 13 and the 6th column would be -8 since thats the only one in the column?

Answer (score 4):

### If you try to calc the row sums

it seems as if there is one loop too much. Your `while` walks through the first dimension and `for(row...` the second dimension. So there is no need to walk through data again by `for(row...`
try it with one loop less like:

```
       public class Testing {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
                                 {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                                 {9, 1, 0, 2},
                                 {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };

                int sum = 0;

                for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < data.length; currentRow++) {
                    sum = 0;
                    for (int col = 0; col < data[currentRow].length; col++) {
                        System.out.println(data[currentRow][col]);
                        sum += data[currentRow][col];
                    } 
                    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
                }   
            }
        }
```

### If you try to calc the column sums

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
                         {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                         {9, 1, 0, 2},
                         {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };
            // get max length of a row == number of columns
        int length = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            int currLength = data[r].length;
            if(currLength>length) length = currLength;
        }
            // create array for column sums
        int[] sums = new int[length];
            // fill array with zeros
        Arrays.fill(sums, 0);
            // sum up
        for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < data.length; currentRow++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < data[currentRow].length; col++) {
                System.out.println(data[currentRow][col]);
                sums[col] += data[currentRow][col];
            } 
        }   
            // print sums
        for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + sums[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I would rather see the `while` converted to a `for` -- if it initializes an int to 0, loops while it is smaller than a maximum, and increments it each time, it looks better as a `for`

Comment: Thanks a bunch sailingthorns, this worked perfectly and I can definitely understand why the array for the sums was needed.  I suppose I was stuck on summing all of the elements of a column one at a time in order instead of spreading it out and summing each incrementally.  Thanks again!

Comment: no problem, glad to help you! It would be nice of you if you can mark my answer as correct or upvote it. thx

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding your question right, and you want the sum of the first, second, third, etc. columns then you could try the following.

```
// array for the sums of the columns
int[] colSums;
int largestSize = 0;

// loop through and find the largest array of values (in this example its the 4th)
for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    largestSize = Math.max(largestSize,data[x].length);
}

colSums = new int[largestSize]; // create the int array with the right length

// loop through the data array and add sums to the colSums array
for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

    colSums[x] = 0; // so that its not null when we add to it

    for(int y = 0; y < data[x].length; y++) {

        // here I add the number to the solSums array
        colSums[y] += data[x][y];
    }
}

// now colSums[0] will be the sum of the first column, colSums[1] = sum of second, etc...
```

Comment: I did not run the code to test it but the idea should be right.

Comment: JStephen, I tested and the first column as well as the last two column totals work correctly though a few in the middle did not add up correctly.  However this idea is similar to the other posted above and is seems just about spot on.  Thanks for your help!